# sqllite3 prepare insert query in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

```
(BOOL) addticket {
    NSString *event=@"max";
    NSString *venue=@"tvm";
    sqlite3 *database;
    databaseName = @"smbhDB.sql";
    sqlite3_stmt *addStatement ;
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    if(addStatement == nil) {   
        const char *sql ="insert into tickets (venue, event,) Values (?,?)";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"444 Error while creating add  statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStatement, 1, [venue UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStatement, 2, [event UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStatement))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    sqlite3_reset(addStatement);
...
```

This code not working. Please can someone help me to correct it. If anybody can post sample code please upload.

Comment: Who in god's name upvoted this?

Comment: Thanks John, for once again reinforcing that this is an "american" forum. It's obvious this guy speaks writes/reads little english. Instead of bsing, why not point this guy to the proper forum, if you know something about it.

Comment: Agreed Stephen. Raju, can you please explain why the code is not working? What is the problem with it?

Comment: I think John's point was that this is not only a very specific question (thus not applicable to others), it is pretty much a duplicate of a question the user had asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862378/sqllite3-prepare-insert-query-in-iphone-programming/862832#862832 .

Comment: @Stephen Cox bad English is forgivable, bad questions are not.

Comment: @Marc: Forgive me father for I have sinned.

Answer (score 3):

Dublicate? [Why can't I execute this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862378/sqllite3-prepare-insert-query-in-iphone-programming/862832#862832)

YOU MUST OPEN DATABASE before execute statement

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, because there's no error detail provided, but it looks like `addStatement` is not being initialized.  Does Objective-C initialize all pointers to 0 when they're allocated on the stack?  I know that in Linux that would not work.

Perhaps try this:  `sqlite3_stmt *addStatement = nil;`

I have to wonder, why are you even checking `addStatement == nil`?  There's no reason to check it, since you must initialize it in every case.

In short, re-write like so:

```
(BOOL) addticket {
    NSString *event=@"max";
    NSString *venue=@"tvm";
    sqlite3 *database;
    databaseName = @"smbhDB.sql";
    sqlite3_stmt *addStatement ;
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    const char *sql ="insert into tickets (venue, event,) Values (?,?)";

    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    /* this is no longer conditional code */
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"444 Error while creating add  statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStatement, 1, [venue UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStatement, 2, [event UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStatement))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    sqlite3_reset(addStatement);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider FMDB or the Omni core data like library. All the details are hidden behind a nice easy abstract interface.

http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/03/fmdb_for_iphone.html

or

http://www.omnigroup.com/developer (OmniDataObjects)

Good luck.