# Prepare insert query on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

This is not working. When I execute this I get one message, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

```
-(void) adddata{
    NSString *event=@"max";
    NSString *venue=@"tvm";
    NSString *edate=@"may 6";
    NSString *etime=@"10:30";
    int admts=5;
    NSString *ima=@"TTTTTTTTT";//ticobj.iimg;
    sqlite3 *database;
    databaseName = @"smbhDB.sql";
    sqlite3_stmt *addStatement=nil ;
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    const char *sql ="insert into tickets (admittance, venue, event, date, time, imagedata) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"444 Error while creating add  statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   sqlite3_bind_int(addStatement,1,admts);
    printf("\n\n inthe add ticket ");
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStatement, 2, [venue UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStatement, 3, [event UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStatement, 4, [edate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStatement, 5, [etime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStatement, 6, [ima UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStatement))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_reset(addStatement);
```

Comment: Usually when you have a "EXEC_BAD_ACCESS" is due to bad memory management. Could you reformat the above code so that we can help analyze this a bit better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqllite3 prepare insert query in iphone programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886167/sqllite3-prepare-insert-query-in-iphone-programming)